# Get data (image toDataUrl) from ajax post request in a servlet

Tags: javascript, image, postgresql, post, request

I tried to get an image from a canvas in javascript and send it with javascript and retrieve it in a servlet in order to put it in a byte array in a postgresql database

My approache was :

Server side :

```
                //Retrieve and get the drawing
            String imageString = req.getParameter("image");
            imageString = imageString.substring("data:image/png;base64,".length());
            byte[] contentData = imageString.getBytes();
            byte[] decodedData = Base64.decodeBase64(contentData);
            //Store the drawing
            stmt.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO drawing (ID_DESIGNER_AUTHOR, DATA) VALUES ('" + currentPlayerID + "', '" + decodedData + "')");
```

client side :

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvasSignature');
var url = canvas.toDataURL();

var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.open("POST", "/drawinguess/sendinfo", false);
xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/upload");
xhttp.send({image:url});
```

But the req.getParameter("image") is null.
If you have any idea of how I can do this, welcome !
Thanks you in advance

Comment: data within the Ajax `send(..)` method is more like `xhttp.send("image=" + url);`

Comment: This is the same, remain null